# How to create a request-response tcp cprogram in java?

Tags: java, tcp, server, client

I was working on a java client-server program but i'm having a hard time creating a tcp socket which will receive one-after-another messages and respond to each one respectively just after the request is made.Because the (-1) aka the termination delimiter received during receiving socket bytes comes after the socket is closed .

--What i wanted to achieve was for e.g.
 (socket conection is implied)

Client>>"request"
Server>>"response"
Client>>"request"
Server>>"Response"
...and so on

How do i do that in JAVA?
Do i have to close and open the socket connection everytime i have to send and receive a message?

Sorry for not explaining it neatly!!
Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: With lines, or. `readUTF()/writeUTF()`, or length words, or type-length-value messages, or Serialization, or XML, or ... Too broad.

Answer (score -1):

MyServer is the server code

```
import java.io.*;  
import java.net.*;  

public class MyServer {  

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{  

        ServerSocket ss=new ServerSocket(6666);  
        Socket s = ss.accept();//establishes connection    

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        //BufferedWriter dout = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()));
        DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

        String str1 = "";
        String str2 = "";

        while(!str1.equals("stop")){

        str1 = din.readUTF();;
        System.out.println("Client: " + str1);

        str2 = br.readLine();

        dout.writeUTF(str2);
        dout.flush();

        }

        din.close();
        s.close();
        ss.close();

    }  
}
```

MyClient is the client code

```
import java.io.*;  
import java.net.*;  

public class MyClient {  

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {  

        Socket s = new Socket("localhost",6666);  

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        //BufferedReader din = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
        DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

        String str1 = "";
        String str2 = "";
        while(!str1.equals("stop")){

        str1 = br.readLine();
        dout.writeUTF(str1);
        dout.flush();

        str2 = din.readUTF();
        System.out.println("Server: " + str2);

        }

        dout.close();
        s.close();  
    }  
}
```

This code allows for two way communication between client and server.
The communication can be stopped by sending stop message from any side.

And remember to send the first message from client to start communication

Comment: You need to handle `EOFException` explicitly, and when you've done that you don't need `"stop"` any more.

Answer (score -1):

This is an example of server multi-threading :

Server.java

```
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server implements Runnable{



    private ServerSocket socket = null;
    private Socket sock = null;
    private boolean running = false;

    public Server(){
        try{
            socket = new ServerSocket(4444);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(!running){
            running = true;
            System.out.println("Server : UP");
            try{
                sock = socket.accept();
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Errore durante l'attesa di nuove connessioni.");
                break;
            }
            ClientThread ct = new ClientThread(sock,this);
            Thread t = new Thread(ct);
            t.start();

            System.out.println("In attesa di connessioni...");

        }

    }

    public void stop(){
        if(running){
            running = false;
            System.out.println("Server : DOWN");
            try{
                socket.close();
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }
        }   
    }

    public boolean isRunning(){
        return running;
    }

}
```

ClientThread.java

```
package Server;

import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ClientThread implements Runnable{

    private Scanner scan;
    private PrintWriter pw;
    private Socket sock;
    private Server main_thread;
    private boolean flag = false;
    private boolean running = true;
    private SenderThread st = null;

    public ClientThread(Socket sock,Server server){
        this.sock = sock;
        this.main_thread = server;

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(flag)
            return;
        flag = true;
        try{
            scan = new Scanner(sock.getInputStream());
            pw = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        while(running){
          try{
            String cmd = scan.nextLine();
            if(cmd.equals("Start")){
                st = new SenderThread(pw);
                Thread t = new Thread(st);
                t.start();
            }
            else if(cmd.equals("Stop")){
                st.stop();
            }
            else{
                running = false;
            }
          }catch(NoSuchElementException e){
              running = false;
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }

        try{
            sock.close();
            scan.close();
            pw.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Listener.java

```
package Client;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Listener implements ActionListener{

    private GuiClient frame;
    private Socket socket;
    private Scanner scan;
    private PrintWriter pw;
    private Receiver receiver = null;

    public Listener(GuiClient gui){
        this.frame = gui;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String cmd = e.getActionCommand();
        if(cmd.equals("Connect")){
            if(frame.ip_textfield.getText() == "" || frame.port_textfield.getText() == "" ){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Dati insufficienti !!!");
            }
            String address = frame.ip_textfield.getText();
            int port = Integer.parseInt(frame.port_textfield.getText());
            try{
                setupConnection(address,port);
                frame.status_label.setText("SERVER UP");
            }catch(Exception e1){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Impossibile stabilire una connessione con il server.");
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            frame.Start.setEnabled(true);
            frame.Connect.setEnabled(false);
            frame.Disconnect.setEnabled(true);
            frame.Stop.setEnabled(false);
        }else if(cmd.equals("Start")){
            //ricevi stringhe e mostrale a schermo
            frame.Start.setEnabled(false);
            frame.Stop.setEnabled(true);
            frame.Connect.setEnabled(false);
            frame.Disconnect.setEnabled(false);
            pw.println(cmd);
            pw.flush();
            try{
              receiver = new Receiver(frame.status_label,scan);
            }catch(Exception e2){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Impossibile ricevere stringhe...");
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Client : "+cmd);
            Thread t = new Thread(receiver);
            t.start();
        }else if(cmd.equals("Stop")){
            frame.Stop.setEnabled(false);
            frame.Disconnect.setEnabled(true);
            frame.Connect.setEnabled(false);
            frame.Start.setEnabled(true);
            try{
                pw.println(cmd);
                pw.flush();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ricezione delle stringhe interrotta.");
            }catch(Exception e1){
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else if(cmd.equals("Disconnect")){
            frame.Connect.setEnabled(true);
            frame.Disconnect.setEnabled(false);
            frame.Start.setEnabled(false);
            frame.Stop.setEnabled(false);
            try{
                socket.close();
            }catch(Exception e1){
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    private void setupConnection(String address, int port){
        try{
            socket = new Socket(address,port);
            OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
            scan = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
            pw = new PrintWriter(os);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Listener works behind the gui client;SenderThread and Receiver are other java class to works with string(in this case).I hope to help you.

Comment: Incorrect exception handling. If there is an exception creating the scanner of the print writer you are ignoring it and proceeding it as though it hadn't happened. If there is an exception creating the client socket or its streams you are swallowing it and letting the client proceed anyway, to a certain NPE. Don't write code like this. Code that depends on the success of code in a prior `try` block should be inside that `try` block, and exceptions should be allowed to propagate instead of being pointlessly swallowed.